# JQGrid column reference is not getting resolved - reference like $('#cocode').val() is shown as undefined for JQGrid column in Spring MVC application

Tags: jqgrid

I have developed an application using Spring MVC + Hibernate + JQGrid. While trying to implement - change in drop down list box values when someone changes values in other list box, I am not able to resolve the JQGrid column reference.

I got demo example from

http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/

I simply copied the code in my application with minor changes for variable names. While I can see the demo running successfully, I am not able to make it run in my code.

I can simply see that JQGrid column reference is not getting resolved, Relevent part of the code is copied below:

```
            function populateBranches() {
            // first of all update the branch based on the company               
            updateBranchCallBack($('#cocode').val(), true);
            // then hook the change event of the company dropdown so that it updates branches all the time
            $('#cocode').bind('change', function (e) {
                updateBranchCallBack($('#cocode').val(), false);
            });
        }

        function updateBranchCallBack(company, setselected) {
    $('#brcode')
                 .html("<option value=''>Loading branches...</option>")
                 .attr("disabled", "disabled");

            $.ajax({
                url: '/NioERPJ/admin/paramgmt/listBranchs/?qcocode='+company,
                async:false,
                type: "GET",
                success: function (branchHtml) {
                    $('#brcode')
                         .removeAttr('disabled')
                         .html(branchHtml);
                }
            });
        };
```

Where there is a reference like $('#cocode').val() or $('#brcode') it is shown as undefined in my application while debugging/running.

Relevent part of the Column definition of the JQGrid is shown below :

```
 colModel:[
                {name:'cocode',index:'cocode',editable:true,edittype:'select',
                    editoptions:{dataUrl:"/NioERPJ/admin/paramgmt/listCmps/qcocode='+$(this).val(),},formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
                {name:'brcode',index:'brcode', width:50, editable:true, edittype:'select', formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
```

I am not able to solve the issue of why I am not getting JQGrid column values from the above mentioned functions? Ironically, I can see the same code running in the demo application.Please help.
I am not asking for debugging of my application, but now I am at my wits end.

Updated Code:

```
    /* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

var row_selected;

 $(document).ready(function() {
        var lastSel;
        var grid = jQuery("#list");

        initDateWithButton = function (elem) {
        if (/^\d+%$/.test(elem.style.width)) {
                // remove % from the searching toolbar
            elem.style.width = '';
        }
            // to be able to use 'showOn' option of datepicker in advance searching dialog
            // or in the editing we have to use setTimeout
        setTimeout(function () {
           $(elem).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                showOn: 'button',
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                showWeek: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                    inst.input.focus();
                }
            });
            $(elem).next('button.ui-datepicker-trigger').button({
                text: false,
                icons: {primary: 'ui-icon-calculator'}
            }).find('span.ui-button-text').css('padding', '0.1em');
            }, 100);
        },
        numberTemplate = {formatter: 'decimal', align: 'right', sorttype: 'number', editable: true, defaultValue:'0.00',
            editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 20,
                        dataInit: function (elem) {
                            $(elem).inputmask("currency",{
                                prefix: "",
                                radixPoint:".", 
                                digits: 2,
                                placeholder: "0.00",
                                digitsOptional: false,
                                autoGroup: false
                             });
                        }},
            searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'nu', 'nn', 'in', 'ni'] }},
        integerTemplate = {formatter: 'decimal', align: 'right', sorttype: 'number', editable: true, defaultValue:'0',
            editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 20,
                        dataInit: function (elem) {
                            $(elem).inputmask("integer",{
                                prefix: "",
                                radixPoint:"", 
                                digits: 0,
                                placeholder: "0",
                                autoGroup: false,
                                digitsOptional: !1,
                                clearMaskOnLostFocus: !1,
                                removeMaskOnSubmit: false,
                                autoUnmask: true
                             });
                        }},
            searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'nu', 'nn', 'in', 'ni'] }},

        dateTemplate = {align: 'center', sorttype: 'date', editable: true,
            formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd/m/Y' }, datefmt: 'd/m/Y',
            editoptions: { dataInit: initDateWithButton, size: 11 },
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge'],
                dataInit: initDateWithButton,
                size: 11,          // for the advanced searching dialog
                attr: {size: 11}   // for the searching toolbar
            }};

        //Load col3 base on col2 selection
/*  function loadCol3Selection(qcocode , col2Selected) {
    var col3Selection = "";
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            async: false,
            url: '/NioERPJ/admin/paramgmt/listBranchs/?qcocode=' + qcocode + '&col2="' + col2Selected + '"',
            success: function (result) {
                $.each(result, function (i, value) {
                    if (value !== 'undefined') {
                       col3Selection ='<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>';
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return col3Selection;
        }*/


         grid.jqGrid({ 
             datatype: 'json', 
             mtype: 'GET', 
             height: 'auto',
             url:'/NioERPJ/admin/paramgmt/',
             editurl:'/NioERPJ/admin/paramgmt/edit',
             colNames:['Company','Branch','Br.Sr.No.','Starting Date','Ending Year','Comp-1','Comp-2','Trade','Domestic SalesLast Code','Domestic Sales Prefix','Export Sales Last Code',
                        'Export Sales Prefix','Domestic Work-Order Last Code','Domestic Work-Order Prefix','Export Work-Order Last Code','Export Work-Order Prefix',
                        'Dispatch Note Last Code','Dispatch Note Prefix','Department Last Code','Location Last Code','Godown Last Code','Gate Pass Last Code',
                        'GRN Last Code','PO Last Code','Non-moving Last Code','CTL3 Last Code','Insp. Note raw Prefix','Insp. Note raw Last Code','Insp. Note gs Prefix','Insp. Note gs Last Code','Username'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'cocode',index:'cocode',editable:true,edittype:'select',
                        editoptions:{dataUrl:"/NioERPJ/admin/paramgmt/listCmps", 
                            dataEvents: [
                    { type: 'change',fn: function(e) {
                        var ret = $.ajax({
                        url:'/NioERPJ/admin/paramgmt/listBranchs/?qcocode='+$(this).val(),
                        async:false
                        }).responseText;
                      $('#brcode').html(ret);
                      }
                    }]
                    },
                    formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
                    {name:'brcode',index:'brcode', width:50, editable:true, edittype:'select', formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
                    {name:'brsrno',index:'brsrno', width:50, editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
                    {name:'fdoy',index:'fdoy', width:110, template : dateTemplate},
                    {name:'feoy',index:'feoy', width:110, template : dateTemplate},
                    {name:'comp1',index:'comp1', width:50, editable:true, editoptions:{size:20, maxlength:30}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
                    {name:'comp2',index:'comp2', width:50, editable:true, editoptions:{size:20,maxlenght:30}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
                    {name:'trade',index:'trade', width:60, editable: true,edittype:"checkbox",editoptions: {value:"true:false"}},
                    {name:'domesticsaleslastcode', index:'domesticsaleslastcode',template : integerTemplate},
                    {name:'domesticsalesprefix',index:'domesticsalesprefix', width:50, editable:true, editoptions:{size:30}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
                    {name:'exportsaleslastcode',index:'exportsaleslastcode', width:50, template : integerTemplate},
                    {name:'exportsalesprefix',index:'exportsalesprefix', width:50, editable:true, editoptions:{size:30}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
                    {name:'domesticworkorderlastcode',index:'domesticworkorderlastcode', width:50, template : integerTemplate},
                    {name:'domesticworkorderprefix',index:'domesticworkorderprefix', width:50, editable:true, editoptions:{size:30}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
                    {name:'exportworkorderlastcode',index:'exportworkorderlastcode', width:50, template : integerTemplate},
                    {name:'exportworkorderprefix',index:'exportworkorderprefix', width:50, editable:true, editoptions:{size:30}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
                    {name:'dispatchnotelastcode',index:'dispatchnotelastcode', width:50, template : integerTemplate},
                    {name:'dispatchnoteprefix',index:'dispatchnoteprefix', width:50, editable:true, editoptions:{size:30}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
                    {name:'departmentlastcode',index:'departmentlastcode', width:50, template : integerTemplate},
                    {name:'locationlastcode',index:'locationlastcode', width:50, template : integerTemplate},
                    {name:'godownlastcode',index:'godownlastcode', width:50, template : integerTemplate},
                    {name:'gatepasslastcode',index:'gatepasslastcode', width:50, template : integerTemplate},
                    {name:'grnlastcode',index:'grnlastcode', width:50, template : integerTemplate},
                    {name:'polastcode',index:'polastcode', width:50, template : integerTemplate},
                    {name:'nonmovinglastcode',index:'nonmovinglastcode', width:50, template : integerTemplate},
                    {name:'ct3lastcode',index:'ct3lastcode', width:50, template : integerTemplate},
                    {name:'inspnoterawprefix',index:'inspnoterawprefix', width:50, editable:true, editoptions:{size:30}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
                    {name:'inspnoterawlastcode',index:'inspnoterawlastcode', width:50, template : integerTemplate},
                    {name:'inspnotegsprefix',index:'inspnotegsprefix', width:50, editable:true, editoptions:{size:30}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
                    {name:'inspnotegslastcode',index:'inspnotegslastcode', width:50, template : integerTemplate},
                    {name:'username',index:'username', width:50, editable:true, editoptions:{size:30}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}}
                ],
             gridview: true,
             toolbar: [false, "bottom"],
             pager: $('#pager'), 
             rowNum:15, 
             rowList:[10,20,30], 
             sortname: 'cocode', 
             sortorder: "asc", 
             viewrecords: true,
             altRows: false, 
             autowidth:true, 
             shrinkToFit:false,
             forceFit:true,
             jsonReader : {
                 root: "rows",
                 page: "page",
                 total: "total",
                 records: "records",  
                 repeatitems: false
                },        
             imgpath: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images', 
             caption: 'Parameters',
             onSelectRow: function(row_id){
                            if(row_id !== null) {
                                 row_selected = row_id;
                                 }
                            if (row_id && row_id !== lastSel) {
                                grid.jqGrid('restoreRow',lastSel);

                                var cm = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','cocode');
                                var cm1 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','brcode');
                                var cm2 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','brsrno');
                                var cm3 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','fdoy');
                                var cm4 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','feoy');
                                var cm5 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','comp1');
                                var cm6 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','comp2');
                                var cm7 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','trade');
                                var cm8 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','domesticsaleslastcode');
                                var cm9 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','domesticsalesprefix');
                                var cm10 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','exportsaleslastcode');
                                var cm11 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','exportsalesprefix');
                                var cm12 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','domesticworkorderlastcode');
                                var cm13 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','domesticworkorderprefix');
                                var cm14 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','exportworkorderlastcode');
                                var cm15 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','exportworkorderprefix');
                                var cm16 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','dispatchnotelastcode');
                                var cm17 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','dispatchnoteprefix');
                                var cm18 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','departmentlastcode');
                                var cm19 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','locationlastcode');
                                var cm20 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','godownlastcode');
                                var cm21 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','gatepasslastcode');
                                var cm22 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','grnlastcode');
                                var cm23 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','polastcode');
                                var cm24 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','nonmovinglastcode');
                                var cm25 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','ct3lastcode');
                                var cm26 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','inspnoterawprefix');
                                var cm27 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','inspnoterawlastcode');
                                var cm28 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','inspnotegsprefix');
                                var cm29 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','inspnotegslastcode');
                                var cm30 = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','username');
                                cm.editable = false;
                                cm1.editable =false;
                                cm2.editable =false;
                                cm3.editable =false;
                                cm4.editable =false;
                                cm5.editable =false;
                                cm6.editable =false;
                                cm7.editable =false;
                                cm8.editable =false;
                                cm9.editable =false;
                                cm10.editable =false;
                                cm11.editable =false;
                                cm12.editable =false;
                                cm13.editable =false;
                                cm14.editable =false;
                                cm15.editable =false;
                                cm16.editable =false;
                                cm17.editable =false;
                                cm18.editable =false;
                                cm19.editable =false;
                                cm20.editable =false;
                                cm21.editable =false;
                                cm22.editable =false;
                                cm23.editable =false;
                                cm24.editable =false;
                                cm25.editable =false;
                                cm26.editable =false;
                                cm27.editable =false;
                                cm28.editable =false;
                                cm29.editable =false;
                                cm30.editable =false;
                                grid.jqGrid('editRow', row_id, true, null, null, 'clientArray');
                                cm.editable = true;
                                cm1.editable = true;
                                cm2.editable = true;
                                cm3.editable = true;
                                cm4.editable = true;
                                cm5.editable = true;
                                cm6.editable = true;
                                cm7.editable = true;
                                cm8.editable = true;
                                cm9.editable = true;
                                cm10.editable = true;
                                cm11.editable = true;
                                cm12.editable = true;
                                cm13.editable = true;
                                cm14.editable = true;
                                cm15.editable = true;
                                cm16.editable = true;
                                cm17.editable = true;
                                cm18.editable = true;
                                cm19.editable = true;
                                cm20.editable = true;
                                cm21.editable = true;
                                cm22.editable = true;
                                cm23.editable = true;
                                cm24.editable = true;
                                cm25.editable = true;
                                cm26.editable = true;
                                cm27.editable = true;
                                cm28.editable = true;
                                cm29.editable = true;
                                cm30.editable = true;
                                lastSel = row_id;
                            }
                        }

     }); 


     $("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : true, defaultSearch:"cn"});
/*     $("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{},{}, {}, {},
     {  // search
         sopt:['cn', 'eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'gt', 'bw', 'ew'],
         closeOnEscape: true,
         multipleSearch: true,
         closeAfterSearch: true
     });*/


     $("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:true,refresh:false}, 
             { 
               recreateForm: true, dataheight: 725, width: 500, height: 800,
//               afterShowForm: populateBranches,
               beforeShowForm: function(form) {$('#trv_cocode',form).hide();}
             },
             { 
              recreateForm: true,  dataheight: 725, width: 500, height: 800,
//              afterShowForm: populateBranches,
              beforeShowForm: function(form) {$('#tr_cocode',form).show();}
             },
             {
             },
             {  // search
                sopt:['cn', 'eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'gt', 'bw', 'ew'],
                closeOnEscape: true,
                multipleSearch: true,
                closeAfterSearch: true
            });
 });

                  // This function gets called whenever an edit dialog is opened
            function populateBranches() {
                // first of all update the city based on the country               
                updateBranchCallBack($('#cocode').val(), true);
                // then hook the change event of the country dropdown so that it updates cities all the time
                $('#cocode').bind('change', function (e) {
                    updateBranchCallBack($('#cocode').val(), false);
                });
            }

            function updateBranchCallBack(company, setselected) {
//      var current = $("#grid").jqGrid('getRowData',$("#grid")[0].p.selrow).brcode;
        $('#brcode')
                     .html("<option value=''>Loading branches...</option>")
                     .attr("disabled", "disabled");

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/NioERPJ/admin/paramgmt/listBranchs/?qcocode='+company,
                    async:false,
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function (branchHtml) {
                        $('#brcode')
                             .removeAttr('disabled')
                             .html(branchHtml);
//              if(setselected) {
//                                  $("#brcode").val( current );
//              }
                    }
                });
            };


$.jgrid.edit = {
     addCaption: "Add Parameter",
     editCaption: "Edit Parameter",
     bSubmit: "Submit",
     bCancel: "Cancel",
     bClose: "Close",
     bYes : "Yes",
     bNo : "No",
     bExit : "Cancel",
     closeAfterAdd:true,
     closeAfterEdit:true,
     reloadAfterSubmit:true,
     msg: {
             required: "is mandatory or required",
             number: "is a number field. Enter a valid number",
             minValue: "should not be less than ",
             maxValue: "should not be more than "
             },
    errorTextFormat: function (response) {
         if (response.status !== 200) {
             return '<div style="overflow-y: scroll;">'+
                "Error encountered while processing. Please check the accuracy of data entered.-" + response.status + " "+response.responseText
                + '</div>';
         }
     },
    afterSubmit : function(response,postdata) {
/*                         return(true,"ok"); */
/*        var myInfo = '<div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all">'+
                     '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" ' +
                     'style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>' +
                     response.responseText +
                    '</div>',
                    $infoTr = $("#TblGrid_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id) + ">tbody>tr.tinfo"),
                    $infoTd = $infoTr.children("td.topinfo");
                    $infoTd.html(myInfo);
                    $infoTr.show();

                    // display status message to 3 sec only
                    setTimeout(function () {
                    $infoTr.slideUp("slow");
                    }, 3000); */

                    return [true, "", ""]; // response should be interpreted as successful
                    }  

 };

 $.jgrid.del = {
     caption: "Delete Parameter",
     msg: "Delete selected Parameter?",
     bSubmit: "Delete",
     bCancel: "Cancel",
     reloadAfterSubmit:true,
     closeOnEscape:true,
     onclickSubmit : function(eparams) {
                             var rowData = $("#list").jqGrid('getRowData', row_selected);
                             var retarr = {'cocode':rowData['cocode']};
                             return retarr;
                             }    
 };
```

UPDATE FOR .JSP file:

```
    <%-- 
    Document   : paramgmt
    Created on : Oct 4, 2015, 10:52:07 AM
    Author     : 
--%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page session="true" %>

<tiles:insertDefinition name="defaultTemplate">
    <tiles:putAttribute name="body"> 

<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/styles/pure-0.4.2.css"/> -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/styles/hfstyles.css" />
 <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/styles/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
 <%--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/styles/jquery-ui.css" />--%>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/styles/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<style type="text/css">
        div.ui-jqgrid-titlebar {
            height: 16px;
        }
    </style>


<div class="body">
 <table id="list" ><tr><td></td></tr></table>
 <div id="pager" style="text-align:center;"></div>

</div>
 <!-- It is advised to put the <script> tags at the end of the document body so that they don't block rendering of the page -->
 <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/script/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/script/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/script/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/script/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/script/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/script/jquery.jqGrid.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
 <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/script/js-for-para.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </tiles:putAttribute>
</tiles:insertDefinition>
```

Comment: Not seeing enough of your code to be certain (including the html might help) but the undefined $('#cocode').val() would tend to indicate that JQuery cannot find and element with the id 'cocode' in the DOM. Until these unresolved reference get fixed your execution is likely to quit before the grid can initialize.

Comment: @DFriend, I have posted entire .JS file, kindly suggest some solution. In the above code I have uncommented the dataEvents: [
                    { type: 'change',fn: function(e) {
                        var ret = $.ajax({
                        url:'/NioERPJ/admin/paramgmt/listBranchs/?qcocode='+$(this).val(),
                        async:false
                        }).responseText;
                      $('#brcode').html(ret);
                      }
                    }]
                    }, Just to debug.

Comment: Is this the demo you meant to link to? http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/edit_add_delete/inline_edit_controls/index.html where the customer id column has a dropdown? Is that what you're trying to react to?

Comment: @DFriend, No, the demo from which I have borrowed code is - guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/edit_add_delete/ - Dialogs: Linked / Dependent dropdowns

Comment: In some other post at http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/dynamically-populate-select-dropdown , it has been suggested by @OlegK that $("select#gs_City").html(res) instead of $("#City").html(res), will solve thae problem, I have tried that also, but not able to set the value of brcode dropdown list.

Comment: Do you run into the undefined reference problem before you open the edit dialog?

Comment: @DFriend, Yes, brcode dropdown is not getting filled up with list of branches.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you first go to the page that shows the grid you get the undefined reference warning and branches is not filled?

Comment: @DFriend, No, it is like this --> First when page opens it displays Grid successfully without any error/warning, I can see all the records/rows  --> After that when I click on + sign to open 'Add new' dialog --> Dialog opens successfully, but only filled in Companies and NOT Branches even after selecting company --> I can see the undefined reference warning in the debug mode when I hover mouse over the $('#brcode'). I hope I am clear.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to updating branches when company dropdown changes:**

This won't help the problem of branches being populated when grid first opens. But it may make branches update when company changes.

Change the first part of colModel as shown here

```
colModel: [
  {name: 'cocode', index: 'cocode', editable: true, edittype: 'select',
    editoptions: {dataUrl: "/NioERPJ/admin/paramgmt/listCmps",
      dataEvents: [
        {type: 'change', fn: function (e) {
            var thisVal = $(e.target).val();
            $.ajax({
              url: '/NioERPJ/admin/paramgmt/listBranchs/?qcocode=' + thisVal,
              dataType: "html" //listBranchs returns html right?
            }).done(function (data) {
              $('#brcode').html(data);
            });
          }
        }]
    },
...
```

Let me know what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have implemented identically, but result is the same --> No list in brcode --> I have put breakpoint on line $('#brcode') ..., when I hover mouse over it, it diaplays "brcode = (ReferenceError) Reference Error: brcode is not defined". I have checked value of 'data' as well  it does contains html for list of branches. Any suggestions.

Comment: Various script files included in the .jsp file is as below: ' jquery-1.11.0.min.js, jquery-ui.min.js, jquery.inputmask.bundle.js, jquery.jqGrid.min.js, grid.locale-en.js'

Comment: One more thing I have observed is that, if I put following line '$(#tr_brcode').html(data), I can see the dropdown list box with required values, but it replaces entire line with label i.e. 'Branch' and listbox. This change displays listbox at extreme left.

Comment: I have placed my .jsp file in the main question for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I have added dummy editoptions values for my dropdownlist, which are being replaced when company is being selected by actual values that come from database.This needs to be done, because while looking at the generated code in inspect element, I found that JQGrid generates element as tr_brcode and nothing like brcode is generated, hence, when we put statement as $('#brcode').html(data) it finds nothing and hence ignores. solution code is as below:

{name:'brcode',index:'brcode', width:50, editable:true,edittype:'select',formatter:'select', editoptions:{value:{1:'One',2:'Two'}},formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},

everything else remains as it is. Thanks for support @DFriend.